# How can I change Display Refresh Rate with Apple Script on Ventura?

Tags: macos, applescript, settings

I want to change the Refresh Rate between 60Hz and ProMotion(120Hz) with Apple Script on Ventura.

System Settings have changed on Ventura and I couldn't find anything about how to write proper Apple Script for this change.

Comment: Can you give a greater context for your use? How/when are you triggering this script? There may be a `defaults write` key that can be set, so you wouldn't necessarily need AppleScript.

Comment: @benwiggy The display is stuttering on the new Macbook Pros if you use ProMotion and low-power Mode combined. So I'm creating a shortcut for it. I want to switch from ProMotion to 60Hz when I switch to low-power mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DisplayPlacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer) is probably what you want. You can install it with Homebrew.

I use it to store defaults for where my laptop it relevant to my desktop monitor (either in a stand horizontally, or vertically below it on my desk.

Then you can store the config and switch between them.

I use an AppleScript script stored in my Scripts folder so it's easily accessible in the menubar.

As you can see, it includes the options for refresh rate, so you can just pick the various options and then store them in the script, switching between them. I have it with a dialog to choose, but you could also just create two scripts and store both in the folder to pick from.

```
set theOptions to {"Desk", "Stand"}
set theChoices to choose from list theOptions with prompt "Select the layout you'd like."

if theChoices contains "Stand" then do shell script "/opt/homebrew/bin/displayplacer 'id:37D8832A-2D66-02CA-B9F7-8F30A301B230 res:1800x1169 hz:120 color_depth:8 scaling:on origin:(0,0) degree:0' 'id:6A89831D-5BCB-4C81-A867-B0E1A52F54F6 res:3840x2160 hz:144 color_depth:7 scaling:off origin:(1800,0) degree:0'"

if theChoices contains "Desk" then do shell script "/opt/homebrew/bin/displayplacer 'id:37D8832A-2D66-02CA-B9F7-8F30A301B230 res:1800x1169 hz:120 color_depth:8 scaling:on origin:(0,0) degree:0' 'id:6A89831D-5BCB-4C81-A867-B0E1A52F54F6 res:3840x2160 hz:144 color_depth:7 scaling:off origin:(-865,-2160) degree:0'"
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you